# Sequelize CLI: db:migrate results in most columns failing to add

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
// package.json
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.5.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"

// terminal
$ node --version
v14.15.4
```

This is the entire migration file I see after running `npx sequelize db:migrate`.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Documents', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Documents');
  }
};
```

Database table inspection using DBeaver shows only one `id` column, not the duplicate seen in the migration file. Two other columns that are always added as well. Everything else is missing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTAwV.png

Under `./models` there is only one file `document.js`, also created by the CLI. I have updated it to this:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Document extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  };
  Document.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.uuid4,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.uuid4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ownerDoc: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ownerName: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.Date,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.Date,
    deletdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.Date,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    uploadBy: {
      type: DataTypes.String, 
      allowNull: true,
    },
    fileUrl: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    fileType: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    }, 
    version: {
      type: DataTypes.number,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    source: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    data: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    }, // any[],
    expiration: {
      type: DataTypes.Date,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    requestAgainExpiration: {
      type: DataTypes.number,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    titleSufix: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    }, 
    inputRequest: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    }, // any[],
    parentId: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    borrowerId: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    loanApplicationId: {
      type: DataTypes.String,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Document',
  });
  return Document;
};
```

Here is the CLI output

```
sean@desktop:~/cp/caBackend$ npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.15.4, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.5.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.


sean@desktop:~/cp/caBackend$ npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.15.4, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.5.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
sean@desktop:~/cp/caBackend$
```

Is anyone able to tell why the migration is failing to update correctly from the model file?

**Tried**

```
// migration file, same one as shown above
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => Promise.all([
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerDoc', { type: Sequelize.String, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerName', { type: Sequelize.String, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'uploadBy', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileUrl', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'category', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'status', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileType', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'version', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'type', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'source', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'data', { type: Sequelize.JSON, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'expiration', { type: Sequelize.Date, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'requestAgainExpiration', { type: Sequelize.NUMBER, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'titleSufix', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'inputRequest', { type: Sequelize.JSON, allowNull: false }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'parentId', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'borrowerId', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'loanApplicationId', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true }),
  ]),
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Documents');
  },
};
```

Both `npx sequelize db:migrate` and `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` show:

```
No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
```

sean@desktop:~/cp/caBackend$ npx sequelize migration:create --name alter-documetns

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return Promise.all([
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerDoc', { type: DataTypes.String, allowNull: false, }),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerName', { type: DataTypes.String, allowNull: false, }),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'uploadBy', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileUrl', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'category', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'status', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileType', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'version', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'type', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'source', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'data', { type: DataTypes.JSON, allowNull: true}),
            
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'expiration', { type: DataTypes.Date, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'requestAgainExpiration', { type: DataTypes.NUMBER, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'titleSufix', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'inputRequest', { type: DataTypes.JSON, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'parentId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'borrowerId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'loanApplicationId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
        ])
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    }
};
```

**npx sequelize migration:create --name alter-documents**

And then replacing default with above code:

```
$ npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.15.4, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.5.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20210306190146-alter-documents: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sean@desktop:~/cp/caBackend$ npx sequelize migration:create --name alter-documents

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
        return Promise.all([
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerDoc', { type: DataTypes.String, allowNull: false, }),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerName', { type: DataTypes.String, allowNull: false, }),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'deletdAt', { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'uploadBy', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileUrl', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'category', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'status', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'fileType', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'version', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'type', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'source', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'data', { type: DataTypes.JSON, allowNull: true}),
            
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'expiration', { type: DataTypes.Date, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'requestAgainExpiration', { type: DataTypes.NUMBER, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'titleSufix', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'inputRequest', { type: DataTypes.JSON, allowNull: false}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'parentId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'borrowerId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
            queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'loanApplicationId', { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}),
        ])
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    }
};
```

**npx sequelize migration:create --name alter-documents**

And then replacing default with above code:

```
$ npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.15.4, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.5.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20210306190146-alter-documents: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: Liam, thank you, is it generally the case that the migration file needs to be updated and run after the first migration to get sequelize to build the table correctly?

Comment: you need update the first migration file,: remove other column

Comment: Or, you can delete the migration meta information, and, remove the wrong table, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYgTc.png

Comment: thanks, tried to run `db:migrate` with both `npx sequelize` and `npx sequelize-cli` in both cases CLI said nothing to update and Dbeaver indicates no update made. Any idea why? I am updating the top post

Comment: we need create new migration file with `npx sequelize migration:create --name alter-documetns`

Comment: Now getting this `ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`. Looks like this will not fix quietly :)

Comment: Fixed answer, check again, `up: (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {`

Comment: did i accidentally edit/erase your answer? So sorry about that! Do you have it posted elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For others who looking for the OP solution:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => Promise.all([
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerDoc', { type: Sequelize.String, allowNull: false })
  ]),
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Documents');
  },
};
```

Result: ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

This above snippet will throw error because datatype must be in UPPERCASE.

Do This

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => Promise.all([
    queryInterface.addColumn('Documents', 'ownerDoc', { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false })
  ]),
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Documents');
  },
};
```

No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.

**Solution:** If you have database access than goto SequelizeMeta table and delete migration file row than you want to excute(Not recommanded for novice) or you can recreate than paste your code.